# HSQLDB: Exit Stored Procedure

Tags: hsqldb, exit, procedure

Is it possible to return from a HSQLDB Stored procedure before reaching its end?

I've tried:

```
IF (condition) THEN
  RETURN;
END IF;
```

This doesn't compile.
Neither with `EXIT` or `LEAVE` instead of `RETURN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRO (VAR INT)
mylabel: BEGIN ATOMIC

  ...
  IF VAR = 3 THEN
   LEAVE mylabel;
  END IF;
  ...

END
```